# Spotify Trial message in login window

Tags: spotify, trial

I'm using CocoaLibSpotify, and it works great. But when the login window comes up, every time I login with my account I see the "Get Spotify!" message afterward, encouraging me to upgrade from a trial account (I have a premium account). Is this just because I don't have the Spotify app installed? (I live in Canada, so it's not available to me). If so, the wording is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's because you don't have the Spotify client installed. The wording will be fixed soon.